# Combining AIC Scores

Tags: aic

I am trying to combine two AIC scores from different parts of a single data set. I have two sigmoidal models that each predict about half of the data (imagine two sigmoidal curves attached end to end), each with a different AIC. I am interested in finding the combined AIC of both curves to represent the single, total AIC of the combined models.  I have been told that this is possible, but I don't know how. Any suggestions are much appreciated!

Comment: Some additional details might help. e.g. This is a single-predictor-single response situation? Is this a nonlinear least squares model or a logistic-regression type model? Can you show a plot of the data with your two models on there? How was the split into two parts done (e.g. is there some a priori criterion by which you split on the predictor, or was it done on the basis of looking at the numbers?)

Answer (score 1):

Nonlinear least squares fitting a growth curve to population data. The models are the same - a logistic growth curve fit to the data. For reasons inherent in the study, the fitting process is split at a particular time point.
[image]